# Assigning a value to a class variable

Tags: c#, comparative-review

I have tried the following code:

```
SystemUser user = (SystemUser)Session["CurrentUser"];
Data.Configuration configuration = db.Configurations.Single(c => c.ID == user.ID);
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("noreply@test.com", "Test");
if (configuration.EmailFromAddress != null)
{
    from = new MailAddress(configuration.EmailFromAddress, "Test"); 
}
```

Here I declare the `from` variable of the `MailAddress` class with a default value, and if `configuration.EmailFromAddress` exists, I am assigning that value to the `from`.

Is this following best practice?

Here, the `MailAddress` class is calling twice to assign the value.  Is it good performance and memory wise? Another implementation is using a string variable:

```
SystemUser user = (SystemUser)Session["CurrentUser"];
Data.Configuration configuration = db.Configurations.Single(c => c.ID == user.ID);
string fromAddress = "noreply@test.com";
if (configuration.EmailFromAddress != null)
{
    fromAddress = configuration.EmailFromAddress;
}
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromAddress, "Test");
```

Which one follows best practice?

Comment: "Is it good performance and memory wise?" It's very likely the difference won't be significant. Don't micro-optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure that `configuration.EmailFromAddress` will always be valid or null, I'd suggest using the [null-coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
SystemUser user = (SystemUser)Session["CurrentUser"];
Data.Configuration configuration = db.Configurations.Single(c => c.ID == user.ID);
var fromAddress = configuration.EmailFromAddress ?? "noreply@test.com";
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromAddress, "Test");
```

In the case that `configuration.EmailFromAddress` can also be empty, I'd use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
SystemUser user = (SystemUser)Session["CurrentUser"];
Data.Configuration configuration = db.Configurations.Single(c => c.ID == user.ID);
var fromAddress = String.IsNullOrEmpty(configuration.EmailFromAddress) ? configuration.EmailFromAddress : "noreply@test.com";
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromAddress, "Test");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `EmailFromAddress` is just a plain field or property then the second version is better because you are not creating an unnecessary object. However when you are comparing strings it is often better to use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (available since .NET 4.0) depending of what the possible values might be. Saul's answer already contains the code showing how to do this.